# Is there any website/program that indicates the estimated queue time at the security check point in a given airport in real time?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, airport-security

Is there any website or program that indicates the estimated queue time at the security check point (e.g. TSA in the US) in a given airport/gate in (near) real time?

Comment: I was just looking for that myself! I have a feeling there isn't one unless an airport is doing it directly.

Comment: @mkennedy I guess it's a timely question with the shutdown in the US ;)

Comment: Doesn't the TSA app include checkpoint wait times?

Answer (score 4):

[The MyTSA App](https://www.tsa.gov/mobile) has some of this information, though it's crowdsourced (plus some historical "how busy is it likely to be" data), and [may be basically useless](https://www.cntraveler.com/story/why-the-tsa-cant-figure-out-how-to-report-wait-times) given a lack of reported results.

There are a few [airports that collect wait time data themselves](https://www.cntraveler.com/stories/2013-08-30/new-airport-tools-to-help-manage-checkpoint-waits-083013) and report it to passengers, including [Dulles (Washington DC)](https://www.mwaa.com/about/get-through-security-faster) (the information is supposedly online in addition to the airport signage, but I have no clue where), [Houston Intercontinental](https://www.fly2houston.com/iah/depart/) (see "Security Checkpoint"), and [Atlanta](http://apps.atl.com/passenger/flightinfo/default.aspx).