# Are security wait times at London Heathrow airport published live on a website?

Tags: airport-security, lhr

Is there any link that gives the current wait times for Heathrow security at departure?

Specifically I was interested in knowing about Terminal 2 departures.

I know Frankfurt and some other airports offer a live estimate at the airport website.

Just wondering if anything similar exists for Heathrow.

Comment: A very quick search does not yield such a service. They only advise people to be at the airport 3 hours before departure…

Comment: FYI [Is there any website/program that indicates the estimated queue time at the security check point in a given airport in real time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/130925/1810)